# Dynamic PDF from html that contains Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, pdf-generation, highcharts, abcpdf

I'm currently working on generating a PDF from a simple html page that contains a few charts that are generated in Javascript using Highcharts.

We currently have ABCPdf installed which generates the PDF, however it doesn't capture any of the charts. After some Googling, I found that adding:

```
theDoc.htmlOptions.UseScript = True
```

Should work, but it doesnt. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: did you resolve that issue? am also facing same issue in charts abcpdf

Comment: No, we never did. We ended up using a different technique to achieve what we wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're currently doing this in production for web pages with javascript that are rendered in pdf to create reports (with HighCharts Graphs)

We're using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Since ABCPDF uses the IE engine: Does your server IE version supports Highcharts? Upgrade if not.
2. You may want to check if Highcharts have to option the generate an image.

Answer (score 0):

The example charts found on [Highchart's website](http://www.highcharts.com/) appear to use SVG.

When I attempted to render their home page with WebSupergoo's [online demo](http://www.abcpdfeditor.com/) for ABCpdf, which uses IE, these also failed to render.

ABCpdf supports only a subset of SVG based around the SVG Tiny specification, according to the [documentation...](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/3-concepts/h-svgsupport.htm)

However, the latest version of ABCpdf introduced support for converting web pages with Gecko's rendering engine. As this engine supports the majority of the SVG Full profile, I would suggest giving it a try. You can find out which bits are not currently implemented here on [Mozilla's site...](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SVG_in_Firefox)

To switch to the Gecko engine you'll need to add something like the following line of code:

```
myDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
```

Each rendering engine also has a different set of HtmlOptions. You can find out more about the [GeckoSubset here...](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf6/xhtmloptions/2-properties/geckosubset.htm)

If this doesn't work, you may need to look at what other formats HighChart can export. Do they support the HTML5 canvas element?

Another thought: Is it possible your charts are fading in and ABCpdf is only capturing the first frame?